# Database certain output to XML

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I have a MySQL database on my website, and I would like to know how I could get a requested XML output via PHP from a table called "customers".

I have this code and it works but I'd like to name a customer and return me only this one.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("eshop");


$query = "select name,address from customer";
$res = mysql_query($query);


$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('customers');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $xml->startElement("customer");

  $xml->writeAttribute('name', $row['name']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('address', $row['address']);

  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
?>
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this. Please note; I am a complete newbie at PHP!

Comment: off topic, mysql procedural function, xml writer ... hmm .. i think u can consider to replace with pdo / mysqli or domdocument / simplexml

Comment: `mysql`-extensions is outdated for a while now. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect . Use `PDO_MYSQL` or `MySQLi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a where clause to your query. And, like others have said, don't ever, ever, EVER use the mysql_* functions. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was simple but I was stack and I have no idea about SQL nor PHP!